# How can I do an if statement inside the jQuery?

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I'm using the jQuery datimepicker (https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

And I would like to make an if statement in my date picker like this:

```
var a = 2;
$("#datetimeTo").datetimepicker({
        minDate:reservationDate,
        maxDate: '+1970/02/01',
        if(a == 2){
            minTime:'20:00', 
        } else {
            minTime:'06:00'
        },
        format:'d/m/Y H:i',
        maxTime:'23:00'
  });
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Try `minTime: a === 2 ? '20:00' : '06:00'`. You can't put if else condition inside JSON like that.

Comment: And if one tries to avoid ternaries for some weird reason, it's always possible to create a simple helper function for this: `const getMinTime = isMorning => { if (isMorning) return '06:00'; return '20:00' }`, then use this helper. Then again, this is exactly what ternaries are about. :)

Comment: @Shubham be careful of the terms you use, this is not `JSON` here, but a plain JS object (and you can't use ternary operators in JSON actually)

Comment: It would be cool if JS supported this synax, unfortunately it doesn't...

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `if-else` there. A ternary operator will work there.

```
    var a = 2;
    $("#datetimeTo").datetimepicker({
        minDate:reservationDate,
        maxDate: '+1970/02/01',
        minTime: a == 2?'20:00':'06:00',
        format:'d/m/Y H:i',
        maxTime:'23:00'
    });
```